# OnAsync Call back FireSharp, FireBase

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms

```
var response = await client.client.OnAsync ("Todo/", (sender, args) => {
  Debug.WriteLine ("Hello");
  Debug.WriteLine (args);
});
```

Im trying to implement Firebase in my application(Xamarin.Forms) https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp.

I am facing an issue, when I Push `Todo` object in Firebase DB it comes to "OnAsync" call back. But in "args" I'm not receiving full `Todo` object.

For example if Todo consists three attributes and I push Todo then `OnAsync` will be called three time, and I'll receive one attribute each time.

So my question is, is there anyway to get a snapshot object or complete full object?

Comment: The link in your question is broken. Also, the question is not really clear; push() will write the ToDo 'object' properties to Firebase. What are you expecting as a response value? Can you add more code so we know what sender and args are? Also, can you update your question with a snippet of your Firebase structure?